# Saving and Using a User Input Image in Xcode with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, image

I am trying to make a simple iOS game of 15 app where I can get user's input image and make a game out of it. I figured out everything else so far but I do not know how to access user's input image.

So I followed what the guideline told me to do, and I managed to get the image in my first page as you can see in the screenshots.
However, I do not know how to save the image, divide it into sixteen tiles and repost in the second page so that users can play with the tiles.

So my question is
1) How do I move the user input image from the first page to second page? Or how do I save the image?

2) how do I split the image in 16 tiles and save them or put them in each image view accordingly?

my code in the first page is

```
import UIKit

class BeginningPage: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageSelector: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    ImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: Action

@IBAction func PressImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, do not post images of your code. [Edit] your question by copying and pasting the actual code text (and be sure it is properly indented and formatted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the image from the first "page" to the second by setting it as a property on the second view controller. (Or a better way to do this might be with a shared view model object.

Look into implementing `prepareForSegue:` inside of your first view controller. There, you can pass the image to the second view controller. The general steps are:

1. In your storyboard, add an identifier to the segue.
2. In your second view controller, add an image property. (Maybe inside of `didSet`, you can chop up the image like you want and add to the second view controller.)
3. In the first view controller, implement `prepareForSegue:` and if the identifier for the segue matches the one you set up in step #1, you pass set the image on the property you created in step 2. (You might need to typecast the segue's destination view controller.)

Your second question is a little more involved. You can start by looking at the documentation for [`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1454683-cgimagecreatewithimageinrect) which will let you break the larger image into smaller ones.